# Handle Blow-Ups in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, spheres, blowup

Hello interested helpers,

my actual problem is that I want to define a solution operator to a "nice" initial value problem, say
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot y = f(y),\\
y(0) = y_0,
\end{cases}
$$
where $f$ is (locally) Lipschitz-continous. This initial value problem has a unique solution on some maximal interval of existence. This is where my problem lies. I want to define a solution operator
$$
S\colon Y\times \mathrm{Lip}(Y,Y)\supset U \to \mathcal C(0,T; Y)
$$
that maps the initial value $y_0$ and the right hand side $f$ to the solution of the problem.
However, if a blow-up occures before the time $T$ this operator is not well defined. To restrict the domain is a bit too bothersome in my case since it might destroy the properties of U.

What I'd like to do, is to introduce a point $\infty$ and extend the solution with infinity after the blow-up. Then the space $\bar Y:= Y \cup\{\infty\}$ can be identified with a sphere in $Y\times \mathbb R$. This should be a manifold with inherited topology from the plane $Y$ onto the sphere via sterografic projection, it has a notion of Cauchy-sequences and their convergence and one can define a curve integral, at least I imagine, that I can.

My imagination reaches its end, however, at the space $\mathcal C(0,T; \bar Y)$. It is not a linear space, due the lack of an additive inverse. If I want to apply Picard-Lindelöfs theorem,
I need at least a complete metric space. Therefore, I consider
$$d_p: \bar Y \times \bar Y \to \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}, 
d_p(y_1,y_2) = \begin{cases}0, & y_1 = y_2;\\
\Vert y_1-y_2\Vert_Y,& y_1,y_2 \in Y;\\
\infty, & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$
and
$$d:\mathcal C(0,T; \bar Y)\times \mathcal C(0,T; \bar Y)\to\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}, d(f,g)=\sup_{t\in [0,T]} d_p(f(t),g(t)).$$
Of course, those are not metrics anymore, but they induce the same topology as we had on the plane $Y$ before and can be used to define pointwise continuity and Lipschitz-continuity.

Has anyone seen this approach before or can tell me, why this is not done anywhere? Where do I hit the wall?

Thanks for reading (and helping).

Comment: It is common to compactify the phase space, but you want to do something similar with the space of solutions. You seem to be assuming that a solution explodes with some kind of limit while this need not be the case, so I wonder what $Y\cup\{\infty\}$ could help if there is nothing like that. It also changes a lot if $Y$ is infinite-dimensional since compact sets need not be the bounded closed sets. I think that you need to formulate your problem better and instead of forcing a solution chosen a priori, you should try to understand how to do what you want that you don't really tell us.

Comment: Well, the main goal would be to do a optimization on $U$ with a restricting ODE as above. In any points of $U$ without any Blow-Up before $T$, the solution operator is continuous (Grönwalls Lemma). However, since I don't know where Blow-Ups occure, I cannot define the solution operator. Therefore I'd like to have it everywhere.

However, I do not want to assume, that the solution explodes with some limit. It my "spiral" it's way up. It reaches $\infty$ in $\tau$ if $\lim_{t\to\tau}\Vert y(t)\Vert =\infty$.